# Is it possible to dynamically add properties to an entity object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, dynamicobject

is it possible to add properties at run-time to a class that was generated by the entity framework? I am successful in doing so with POCO classes that inherit from DynamicObject but when I try to do the same thing with my entity classes, I receive the error "Partial declarations of [class name] must not specify different base classes".

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually pretty surprised that works with L2S; `DynamicObject` is a curious beast, after all. You *could* try ensuring you are using the EF 4 [POCO support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx), rather than the 3.5SP1-style common-base-class approach, but to be honest I'm not sure this is the way to go... database objects shouldn't really *have* dynamic properties, IMO.

Your intent isn't clear, but if this is for data-binding purposes, you might want to look at custom object models, via `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or `TypeDescriptionProvider`. This is an older technology for *seeming* to extend objects at runtime (without needing `dynamic`).

Comment: I don't know with Linq-to-SQL, but it definitely doesn't work with 4.0 of the entity frameowrk but only with the POCO classes that I create from scratch. I would like to add properties to the auto-generated entities at runtime b/c we are retrieving name-pair values that vary per tenant.

Comment: @user327066 - have you tried the POCO tools? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx